# "Constructor Not Defined" in Test Class

Tags: apex, case

I am trying to test that a page successfully redirects to a ThankYou page. I havea  page and controller, some of which are below:

Page:

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Case" extensions="PartnerSupportCaseController">

<div>
              Description
              </div>
              <div>
              <apex:inputTextArea required="true" rows="5" value="{!Case.Description}" label="Description" />
              </div>

<apex:commandLink id="Submit" action="{!save}" styleclass="btn btn btn-primary" style="background-color : Green; background-image:none; color:#002233;">Submit</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller:

```
public class PartnerSupportCaseController {

public Case supportCase {get;set;}

public Attachment attachedFile;

private static Boolean isThereFile = True;

public String sEmail;

public String dEmail;

public String sPhone;

public String fixedPhone;

public String finalPhone;

List<String> emailDomains = new List<String>{***SomeEmailDomains***}


           public PartnerSupportCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

    this.supportCase = (Case)controller.getRecord();
    supportCase.Protocol_Sub_Issue__c = 'Partner Support - Please Pick';
    supportCase.RecordTypeId = '012M000000092ju';

}


public pagereference Save() {

upsert supportCase;
PageReference pg = Page.PartnerSupportThankYou;
    pg.setredirect(true);

    return pg;      
   }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class PartnerSupportCaseController_Test {

static testMethod void testPartnerCase(){

    Test.startTest();

    PartnerSupportCaseController controller = new PartnerSupportCaseController();
    String nextPage = controller.save().getUrl();

    System.assertEquals('/apex/PartnerSupportThankYou', nextPage);

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

}

The problem that I am running into is that I get an error "Constructor not defined [PartnerSupportCaseController].()"  I am having difficulty figuring out where I went wrong in setting up the controller and trying to access it with this test class. I just need it to verify that it successfully redirected to the thank you page.

Thanks,

CP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code uses a controller extension with this constructor:

```
public PartnerSupportCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
```

So your testmethod needs to use the same constructor with an argument of the `apexPages.StandardController`

```
....
// Mock a Case or use an empty Case
Case cs = new Case(accountId = someMockedAccountId, subject='foo', ...);

// Create a standard controller using the Case created above
ApexPages.StandardController ctlr = new ApexPages.StandardController(cs);

// Create an instance of the extension class and pass in the standard controller
PartnerSupportCaseController controller = new PartnerSupportCaseController(ctlr);


//... do stuff in your extension class and then assert results
```